# How to add a texture to dynamically generated terrain vertices in xna

Tags: c#, xna, coordinates, textures

I'm trying to add texture coordinates to each of the vertices so that a grass texture is added to each triangle. The code I have stretches the texture across the entire area which works but doesn't scale up very well. How do I correctly add (0,0), (0,1), (1,1), etc to the vertices?
Currently they're added in the SetUpVertices() method, should they be added in the SetUpIndices() method when the code can distinguish whether it's top left, bottom left, bottom right, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The relevant methods are below and the full Game1.cs code is here http://pastebin.com/REd8QDZA

```
    private void SetUpVertices()
    {
        vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[terrainWidth * terrainHeight];
        for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < terrainHeight; y++)
            {
                vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Position = new Vector3(x, -y, heightData[x, y]);
                vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].TextureCoordinate.X = x / (terrainWidth - 1.0);
                vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].TextureCoordinate.Y = y / (terrainHeight - 1.0);
            }
        }
    }
    private void SetUpIndices()
    {
        indices = new short[(terrainWidth - 1) * (terrainHeight - 1) * 6];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < terrainHeight - 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth - 1; x++)
            {
                int lowerLeft = x + y * terrainWidth;
                int lowerRight = (x + 1) + y * terrainWidth;
                int topLeft = x + (y + 1) * terrainWidth;
                int topRight = (x + 1) + (y + 1) * terrainWidth;

                indices[counter++] = (short)topLeft;
                indices[counter++] = (short)lowerRight;
                indices[counter++] = (short)lowerLeft;

                indices[counter++] = (short)topLeft;
                indices[counter++] = (short)topRight;
                indices[counter++] = (short)lowerRight;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify

```
vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].TextureCoordinate.X = x;
vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].TextureCoordinate.Y = y;
```

By default, texture coordinates greater than 1 will be wrapped and the texture is repeated.

Comment: I've been at this one for days and that's the answer? FFS!!!! Thank you Nico, you're a star.